# Death ward protection vs Characteristic loss

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Does DeathWard protect the objective against characteristic loss, consequence of... I don't know.... Venom? Necromantic spells, or any other form of Wis/Con/Dex, etc loss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer is No**

From the description of the spell:

> The subject is immune to all death spells, magical death effects,
>   energy drain, and any negative energy effects.
>
> This spell doesn’t remove negative levels that the subject has already
>   gained, nor does it affect the saving throw necessary 24 hours after
>   gaining a negative level.
>
> Death ward does not protect against other sorts of attacks even if
>   those attacks might be lethal.

Okay, so in order to be protected the effect has to either

1. Have the [death] descriptor
2. Be a magical death Effect
3. Cause energy drain (usually negative levels)
4. Be a negative energy effect

So, from your examples,

1. Venom - Nope, not at all.
2. Necromancy Spells - Not usually, unless it meets one of the 4 above
3. Other - Nope, unless it meets one of the 4 above.